# .NET Code Security Review Tool

Tags: .net

I am looking for a utility that can be used against .NET assemblies to validate code against best practices, and most importantly can review the code for Security, Injection, and Cross Site Scripting vulnerabilities.  I know that it isn't an exact science, but I'm looking for anyones experience/recommendations on the best way to a solution that will at least set a baseline standard.  I know that nothing beats doing an individual review, but I'm looking at the high level.

I have been doing some research on [Fortify](http://www.fortify.com/products/detect/in_development.jsp), and so far it is looking like a good tool, from what I can tell it provides a very detailed response.  I know that FXCop is out there as well, but I don't know if it goes in deep enough.

**EDIT**  One attractive thing I found about Fortify, and that would be nice in a tool is the combination of security review, AND .NET Best practices review.  IE fortify checks fo potential un-closed connections, recommends the use of Using statements, etc.

Comment: FXCop is a handy tool, but you're right, it doesn't go far enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) is a static code analysis tool, though not specifically targetting security, it will pick up alot of common errors (be sure to turn off the naming rules you aren't interested in).

Also, I came across the "Performance Code Review Tool – Practices Checker" [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/alikl/archive/2008/01/21/performance-code-review-tool-practices-checker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

We have licenses for [Ounce](http://www.ouncelabs.com/) for the development side, and I've heard great things about SpiDynamics for testing applications post development.

Comment: Ounce looks pretty good, does it do anything for "best practices" recommendations as well?

Comment: It says something along those lines on the product page, but I can't be certain. We all have licenses, but ironically not many of us have disk space left to install it.

Best practices copy: http://www.ouncelabs.com/homesdlc.asp